# Flink Watermark

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Flink, I found 2 ways to set up watermark,

the first is

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.getConfig.setAutoWatermarkInterval(5000)
```

the second is

```
env.addSource(
    new FlinkKafkaConsumer[...](...)
).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
   WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness[...](Duration.ofSeconds(10)).withTimestampAssigner(...)
)
```

I would like to know which will take effect eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no conflict at all between those two -- they are dealing with separate concerns. Everything specified will take effect.

The first one,

```java
env.getConfig.setAutoWatermarkInterval(5000)
```

is specifying how often you want watermarks to be generated (one watermark every 5000 msec). If this wasn't specified, the default of 200 msec would be used instead.

The second,

```java
env.addSource(
    new FlinkKafkaConsumer[...](...)
).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
   WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness[...](Duration.ofSeconds(10)).withTimestampAssigner(...)
)
```

is specifying the details of how those watermarks are to be computed. I.e., they should be generated by the `FlinkKafkaConsumer` using a `BoundedOutOfOrderness` strategy, with a bounded delay of 10 seconds. The `WatermarkStrategy` also needs a timestamp assigner.

There's no default `WatermarkStrategy`, so something like this second code snippet is required if you want to work with event time.

Comment: From the source code of BoundedOutOfOrderness strategy, the watermark sent to the downstream is defined by the bounded delay i assigned here which is 10 seconds. So my understanding is if the downstream operator hasn't defined any watermark strategy, 5 seconds will be used?

Comment: No, the 5 second interval is measuring something else entirely. This controls how frequently the WatermarkStrategy is asked to produce a watermark, by calling its `onPeriodicEmit` method.